# What's wrong with this UPDATE statement for MS-Access?

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2008, ms-access

I am trying to update a field based on a field from another table (PricePlan). In PricePlan i have 2 fields, 'Guest' and 'Member' and column 'Price' but in this case i would like 'Price' in my another table to update according to 'Guest's value. When i debug i get the following error in VS2008 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Operation must use an updateable query.

What's wrong with my `UPDATE` statement?

```
UPDATE Bill 
SET Price = ( SELECT PricePlan.Price 
              FROM PricePlan 
              WHERE PricePlan.PricePlanName = 'Guest'
            )
WHERE EXISTS (Select PricePlan.Price 
              FROM PricePlan 
              WHERE PricePlan.PricePlanName ='Guest'
             );
```

Comment: Well what's the problem?  Error?  Not updating as you expect?  You have to provide more details.

Comment: Hi, when i debug i get the following error in VS2008 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Operation must use an updateable query.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recall, these update statements go more like:

```
UPDATE Bill
SET Price = PricePlan.Price
FROM (SELECT Price FROM PricePlan 
      WHERE PricePlanName = 'Guest')
```

But I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to accomplish. Can you provide an example of what the tables would contain, in a before-and-after scenario?

**EDIT**

Based on http://dbaspot.com/forums/ms-access/138825-select-inside-update.html, I'm guessing something like this will probably work:

```
UPDATE Bill,PricePlan 
SET Bill.Price = PricePlan.Price
WHERE PricePlan.PricePlanName = 'Guest'
AND ... (put something here to limit which bills you want to update)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.

Table: Price Plan
Columns: PricePlanName, Price
Fields: Guest, 3
Member, 2

Table: Bill
Columns: Price

For example when i click on the 'Guest' button, it will carry out the SQL update statement to fill or update the 'Price' of Table 'Bill' according to PricePlan's Guest Price, which is a value of 3.

Comment: @pacheco: See if my edit helps. And like cyberkiwi says, please update your own question with additional data rather than putting everything in comments.

Comment: Hi there StriplingWarrior. Your codes are exactly what i wanted to achieve, many thanks! I'm new here, is there any way i can increase your reputation or something? :)

Comment: @pacheco: Welcome to StackOverflow! By accepting my answer, you gave me +15 reputation. As you continue to post questions and answers, you will gain reputation of your own. Once you have 15 reputation, you can "up vote" any questions and answers that you think are a good contribution to StackOverflow. By upvoting questions and answers, you will increase the reputation of the people who posted them. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing is 'wrong' per se with you code: it is Intermediate Standard SQL-92 code and nicely formatted too :)

Sadly, Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) is not SQL-92 compliant, not even Entry Level. The `UPDATE` syntax is its worst failure, IMO. Circa Access 2000 the SQL Server team took ownership of the engine and tried to make it compliant with Standards but was blocked by the Windows team, who had too much code dependent on [Access's proprietary UPDATE syntax](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/update-statement-HA001231523.aspx). It will now never implement SQL-92, there is no hope.

It is Access that is 'wrong'. I urge you to move to a more capable SQL product. SQL Server 2008 Express would be my personal choice.

If you cannot/will not move, then you are forced to learn Access's proprietary syntax (not just `UPDATE`!) along with suffering its many other quirks and limitations.

Answer (score 0):

The most glaring error is that there is **no correlation** between the updated table `Bill` and the subquery! What are you trying to do?

Maybe something like the below?

```
UPDATE Bill inner join PricePlan on PricePlan.Id = Bill.Id
SET Bill.Price = PricePlan.Price
WHERE PricePlan.PricePlanName = 'Guest'
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your codes and it seems to be working for 'Guest'. My Price for table Bill updates to the value '3', however when i change the statement 'WHERE PricePlan.PricePlanName = 'Member', it doesn't seem to update to the value '2' :(

Comment: @pac - What is your actual query used? Please update question and add info instead of trying to cram into comments. Probably a wrong join somewhere.